# IOS XML-Parsing Get image in UItableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, xml-parsing

I am working on XML parsing demo. I have successfully fetch title of RSS feed. And I am trying to get image from rss feed but I am not able to understand how to get image in UITableview.

Here is my try.

```
// Viewcontroller.h file //
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController<NSXMLParserDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
NSXMLParser *parser;
NSMutableArray *feeds;
NSMutableDictionary *item;
NSMutableString *title;
NSMutableString *link;
NSString *element;
NSString *img;
NSMutableArray *arrImages;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tbl;

//viewcontroller.m file //

 - (void)viewDidLoad 
{
   feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/World.xml"];
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
[parser parse];
 }
#pragma mark - XML parser Delegate method

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

element = elementName;

if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

    item    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    title   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    link    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    img =[[NSMutableString alloc]init];

}
  }

  - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

    [item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
    [item setObject:link forKey:@"link"];
    [item setObject:img forKey:@"img"];
    [feeds addObject:[item copy]];

}

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
    [title appendString:string];
} else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
    [link appendString:string];
}
else if ([element isEqualToString:@"img"])
{
    [link appendString:string];
}

}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

[self.tbl reloadData];

}

#pragma mark - UITableview Datasource Method

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 return feeds.count;
}
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   //    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
NSMutableDictionary* info = [feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Badal"];
cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
cell.textLabel.text = [info objectForKey: @"title"];
NSString* str = [info objectForKey:@"img"];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
NSData *dataget=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];

UIImage *imgget=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:dataget];
cell.imageView.image=imgget;
 return cell;
 }
```

EDIT:-

getting Response like this With Debug.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check  below method:-

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
[title appendString:string];
} else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
[link appendString:string];
}
else if ([element isEqualToString:@"img"])
{
[img appendString:string]; // Change is HERE
}

}
```

change is you are appending img url to link string.Check you dictionary for value img.NSlog it before reloading tableview.

Comment: thanks a lot for the replay. but don't success. please check edited question getting response like that with debug.

Comment: have u make change in foundCharacter method ?

Comment: As there is no url in "img" key of dictinary

Comment: so, what i have to do next to get image ? because there is image available in feed.

Comment: Have you made changes in parser foundcharacter method ? As I have suggested

Comment: as per you said i did it.